# Docker broke my brew?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, homebrew

I worked on my computer (mac os High Sierra 10.13.4) for a Rails application. I had Postgres, Redis and ElasticSearch installed via Homebrew.
I recently started to dockerize the app on a new branch.

When I went back to my main branch, none of the brew services were working:

- `PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused`
  which I fixed thanks to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75214/postgresql-not-running-on-mac
- couldn't connect to redis
  which I fixed by running `redis-cli`
- `Errno::ECONNREFUSED - Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "::1" port 9200)`

I tried stopping/starting, desinstalling/reinstalling elasticsearch and even desinstalling/reinstalling Homebrew. I'm considerating doing a clean reinstall of my computer.

I don't understand how working on docker could break services on my computer, I thought it was supposed to fix exactly that kind of problems.

Any help on getting elasticsearch to work would be really appreciated!

Comment: It might be because none of those services are slated to start on boot. You need to manually start all of they if you never set them to start on boot.

Comment: I tried to brew services stop/start postgresql elasticsearch and redis but it didn't fix my issue.

Comment: Have you looked at the log files for each of them?

Comment: Please use the [homebrew] tag instead of [brew], which has nothing to do with that. I edited your question to fix the tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> This answer is only a speculation. A little more information might help us figure out what’s really going on here.

*Are the Docker containers still running?*
*If yes, do they use the same ports that these services do on your Mac?*

If the answer to both the above questions was ***yes***, then you’ve found your problem.

What I mean to say is that if the containers are running and one of them is mapped to the port `9200`, which also happens to be the port on which the required services on your Mac listen to by default, then these services cannot run on that port as it is already being used by one of your containers.

**Solution:** If this is the case, stop the containers and try running your services again